# Get JavaScript Map values as array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is there like a quick way to get Javascript Map values as an array?

```
const map:Map<number, string> = new Map()
map.set(1, '1')
map.set(2, '2')
```

And then something like `Array.from(map.values())` would give `['1','2']` ...  I could have sworn that I've something like this...?

Comment: `[...yourMap.values()]`

Comment: It's an iterator ...

Comment: What you suggested in your question works as well: `Array.from(map.values())`

Comment: @Ole `map.values()` is an iterator. `[...someIterator]` is an array.

Comment: @Paul - OK I LIKE ... - Thanks!

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov sorry I did not catch the syntax right way.  Very cool!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is working fine. [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) can take an iterable value as well.

```js
const map = new Map;

map.set(1, '1');
map.set(2, '2');

console.log(Array.from(map.values()));
```

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative could be using **Spread syntax** (`...`).

```js
const map = new Map().set(4, '4').set(2, '2');
console.log([...map.values()]);
```